# ffmpeg: how to convert mov file to gif , and gif is resized

Tags: mac, video, ffmpeg, conversion

how to use `ffmpeg` to convert mov file to gif , and gif is resized directly?

Here is the [raw file](https://github.com/ForStackO/picker/blob/master/src/input.mov)

I firstly convert mov to gif,

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -pix_fmt rgb24 output.gif`,

then use `imageMagick` to resize the gif.

```
convert   output.gif -coalesce temporary.gif
convert -size 756x1504   temporary.gif -resize 189x376 smaller.gif
```

Here is the result:

[image: 000]

How to use `ffmpeg` to do this directly, without using `imagemagick`

Comment: Have you tried using the resizing options in ffmpeg? Please do some research before asking. (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling)

Comment: See the duplicate question for various options related to creating GIFs with ffmpeg, including resizing.